# UIPickerView height constraint animation jumps

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview, uiviewanimation

I'm animating the height constraint of an UIPickerView.
The View jumps to a small height still showing 1 row and then animates till height 0.

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
        self.timePickerHeightConstraint.constant =    self.pickerIsClosed ? 216 : 0
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }) { compilation in
        self.pickerIsClosed = !self.pickerIsClosed
    }
```

Any suggestions? 
Thanka

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this,

```
func showPickerView(_ animated: Bool) {
    weak var weakSelf = self
    UIView.animate(withDuration: (animated ? kPickerView_AppearanceAnimationDuration : 0.0), delay: (animated ? kPickerView_AppearanceAnimationDelay : 0.0), options: (animations as! UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut), {() -> Void in
        weakSelf!.pickerViewContainerView.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: 0)
    }, completion: {(finished: Bool) -> Void in
        weakSelf!.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    })
}

func hidePickerView(_ animated: Bool) {
    weak var weakSelf = self
    UIView.animate(withDuration: (animated ? kPickerView_DisappearanceAnimationDuration : 0.0), delay: (animated ? kPickerView_DisappearanceAnimationDelay : 0.0), options: (animations as! UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut), {() -> Void in
        weakSelf!.pickerViewContainerView.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: kPickerView_Height)
    }, completion: {(finished: Bool) -> Void in
```

It works for me.

Answer (score 1):

You should change the constraints constant value outside of animation block,

```
self.timePickerHeightConstraint.constant =    self.pickerIsClosed ? 216 : 0

UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}) { compilation in
    self.pickerIsClosed = !self.pickerIsClosed
}
```

Also make sure you do not set Top and Bottom constraint as that will not allow auto layout to set height to 0 pts.

Comment: Thanks, but same problem.

Comment: What constraints you have set for the PickerView?

Comment: trailing, leading, height, top, bottom

Comment: In that case changing height to 0 will not work as auto layout engine would need to break constraint. Try setting Vertical and Horizontal centre constraint and set Width and Height constraint and just make outlet of Height constraint and update.change it as per need.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue. It appears UIPickerView's height doesn't really animate well, or at least animate in the way I hoped.

The workaround I found was to wrap the UIPickerView inside a UIView, having the UIView's clipsToBounds set to true, and then do the animation on the height constraint of the UIView wrapper, instead of the UIPickerView directly. One thing to note is that for this to work, the height of the UIPicker view has to be constrained independently of the wrapper view's height, because otherwise it'll react the same way as with no wrapper.

```
 // create and add UIPicker to view
    UIPickerView *picker = [[UIPickerView alloc] init];
    picker.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.dataSource = self;
    picker.alpha = 0.0;
    _myUiPicker = picker; // weak reference property

    // make wrapper view
    UIView *wrapper = [UIView new];
    wrapper.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    wrapper.clipsToBounds = YES;
    [wrapper addSubview:picker];
    [self.view addSubview:wrapper];

    // Picker constraints
    [picker.leadingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:wrapper.leadingAnchor].active = YES;
    [picker.trailingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:wrapper.trailingAnchor].active = YES;

    // ***** Note this height is not determined by wrapper view ***
    [picker.heightAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:130.0].active = YES;
    // ****
    [picker.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:wrapper.topAnchor].active = YES;

    // wrapper constraints
    [wrapper.leadingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.leadingAnchor].active = YES;
    [wrapper.trailingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.trailingAnchor].active = YES;
    // **** this is the constraint you will animate ***
    NSLayoutConstraint *heightConstraint = [wrapper.heightAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:0.0];
    heightConstraint.active = YES;
    // ****
    NSLayoutConstraint *topConstraint = [wrapper.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.topAnchor constant:8.0];
    topConstraint.active = YES;
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded]; // initial layout

    // animate picker height and reminderBtn position
    [UIView animateWithDuration:JAPPickerAnimationTime animations:^{
        heightConstraint.constant = 130.0; // from 0 to 130
        picker.alpha = 1.0; // make is show
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    }];
```

Comment: sound like a good solution - could you show some code ? I do not understand your last sentence (i..e independent constraint need). Could you elaborate a bit more on how you did this ?

Comment: @iKK I've added a code example. What I mean about independent heights is that the constraint that sets the height of the UIPickerView is not related, or tied, to the height of the UIView that is acting as a wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

What is Hight of row of picker component . check in

> func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, rowHeightForComponent component: Int)

return  0 when  self.pickerIsClosed == true.

Comment: also reload picker view on completion of animation block.